# \cprotect and \verb command within a starred section title

Tags: sectioning, verbatim

I created a section title using `\cprotect` and `\verb`. The unstarred version works fine, but the starred one doesn't. How should I use these commands properly? Thank you.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cprotect}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\begin{document}

\cprotect\section{Using \verb|\cprotect| command}
\kant[1]

% starred version:
\cprotect\section*{Using \verb|\cprotect| command} % this produces an error
\kant[2]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cprotect}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\begin{document}

\cprotect\section{Using \verb|\cprotect| command}
\kant[1]

% starred version:
\cprotect{\section*}{Using \verb|\cprotect| command} % this produces an error
\kant[2]

\end{document}
```